# Is It possible to update call status to Server?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call

I am trying to fetch  call status. I managed to get that, getting call status using **BroadcastReceiver**.
my doubt is it possible to send call status to server. For example `CALL_STATE_RINGING` etc. through web service. I tried but its only updating `CALL_STATE_IDLE` state. Please give your opinion.

Comment: Please explain your question. It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Also, this is a question and answer site. We aren't interested in anyone's "opinions". We want facts and only facts.

Answer (score 0):

In the Broadcast receiver you can get the call state using intent

Here is the code:

```
 String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

       if (stateStr != null) {
                int state = 0;
                try {
                    if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                    } else if (stateStr
                            .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                    } else if (stateStr
                            .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                    } else if (stateStr
                            .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "State String :" + stateStr);
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                }
```

Comment: I am getting call status..i want to know that is it posible to update to server.using any webservice

Comment: use any mbaas platform